# Why the Chinese texts do not appear in Flutter app sometimes?

Tags: android, flutter

[image]

I have an app that is using Flutter.
Some users say that they can’t see the Chinese text when they open the app sometimes.

The first image is the normal state.
The second image is the user’s screen capture, you can see that all of the Chinese text does not appear.

There was no issue before I updated Flutter from 3.7 to 3.13 and the issue was only reported by Android users. If the user uninstalls the app and then reboots the phone and then reinstalls the app, it will be ok.

I can’t reproduce this by myself. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks very much.

updated on 10.19:

The below text is the error when the Chinese texts do not appear:

```
2023-10-19 11:57:55.904 25798-25961 SuggestManager          com.miui.securitycenter.remote       E  openApp name = com.xxx.xxx
2023-10-19 11:57:55.910  9459-9459  ForceDarkHelper         com.xxx.xxx                 D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.xxx.xxx activity: com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity@b27f842
2023-10-19 11:57:55.911  9459-9490  ViewContentFactory      com.xxx.xxx                 D  initViewContentFetcherClass
2023-10-19 11:57:55.911  9459-9490  ContentCatcher          com.xxx.xxx                 I  ViewContentFetcher : ViewContentFetcher
2023-10-19 11:57:55.911  9459-9490  ViewContentFactory      com.xxx.xxx                 D  createInterceptor took 0ms
2023-10-19 11:57:55.911  9459-9459  ForceDarkHelper         com.xxx.xxx                 D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.xxx.xxx activity: com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity@b27f842
2023-10-19 11:57:55.912  9459-9459  chatty                  com.xxx.xxx                 I  uid=10295(com.xxx.xxx) identical 1 line
2023-10-19 11:57:55.912  9459-9459  ForceDarkHelper         com.xxx.xxx                 D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.xxx.xxx activity: com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity@b27f842
2023-10-19 11:57:55.932  9459-9459  ForceDarkHelper         com.xxx.xxx                 D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.xxx.xxx activity: com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity@b27f842
2023-10-19 11:57:55.932  9459-9459  ForceDarkHelper         com.xxx.xxx                 D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.xxx.xxx activity: com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity@b27f842
2023-10-19 11:57:55.953  9459-9459  ForceDarkHelper         com.xxx.xxx                 D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.xxx.xxx activity: com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity@b27f842
2023-10-19 11:57:55.958  9459-9459  EgretLoader             com.xxx.xxx                 D  EgretLoader(Context context)
2023-10-19 11:57:55.959  9459-9459  EgretLoader             com.xxx.xxx                 D  The context is not activity
2023-10-19 11:57:55.975  9459-9459  SurfaceView             com.xxx.xxx                 D  UPDATE null, mIsCastMode = false
2023-10-19 11:57:55.998  9459-9459  ForceDarkHelper         com.xxx.xxx                 D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.xxx.xxx activity: com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity@b27f842
2023-10-19 11:57:56.001  9459-9459  EgretLoader             com.xxx.xxx                 D  EgretLoader(Context context)
2023-10-19 11:57:56.001  9459-9459  EgretLoader             com.xxx.xxx                 D  The context is not activity
2023-10-19 11:57:56.024  9459-9459  ForceDarkHelper         com.xxx.xxx                 D  updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.xxx.xxx activity: com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity@b27f842
2023-10-19 11:57:56.028  9459-9459  EgretLoader             com.xxx.xxx                 D  EgretLoader(Context context)
2023-10-19 11:57:56.029  9459-9459  EgretLoader             com.xxx.xxx                 D  The context is not activity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue maybe, but I still don't know the root reason.

I changed the main function from async to sync and moved the async codes in the main to other places.

Before:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // ...
  await PackageInfo.fromPlatform()
  // ... there are a few async methods

  runApp(const RestartApp(child: MyApp()));
}
```

After:

```dart
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Every async methods were removed

  runApp(const RestartApp(child: MyApp()));
}
```

I can't reproduce the issue on my Android test drive(Android 10) after I made this change. I don't know if it is okay on the phone that my app users, I will change the answer if someone reports to me.